# CSS - Blend edges of image with background image

Tags: html, css, image

So I have an developing a basic website and used some images with cool light effects but the change in color hits the edge of the page, this is the image:
[image]

So as you can see the light in the image reaches the edge so what I am wanting to know, is there a way to blend the edges in css or html so they look good and not like that? I've looked all over the web and can't find anything really relating to my problem...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll need to adjust the image itself to make sure that the gradient fades all the way to black.

Comment: Something like and inset box-shadow could do this, but you're probably better off editing the image's size

Comment: Could you please provide an example in http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to accomplish that, but the only good way is to take care of your edges when producing the image. Clear and simple. If your page has a black background, make sure you have an image background of the same color. Then fade your "light effect" into that same color before hitting the edge using your favorite image manipulation program.

I advice against producing an image with a transparent background - your image is large and performance will be slightly smacked.

If you truly want to experiment with fading post-production, you could use CSS gradients to make the image seem to fade off at the edges. Or use (vendor specific) CSS3 toys like `box-shadow` (see [Box shadow on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2Fbox-shadow)) to produce an inset, black shadow.

Keep in mind though that all these tricks, specially on such huge images as you presented, have their cost in browser performance (and thus user experience) and are not supported widely (specially older browsers). Also, many mobile devices will not thank you for the effects show.